# What is meant by "Noisy Optimization"?

Tags: optimization

Does anyone know what is meant by "Noisy Optimization"?

Typically, I always thought that "Noise" refers to "unwanted signals" that distort the data/function that you are studying - in many applications (e.g. signal processing, electrical engineering, time series, etc.), we are interested "de-noising" our data (i.e. removing the "noise" from the "true signal"):

[image]

However, in the context of optimization, I am not sure if "noisy optimization" refers to this, or whether it refers to something else. For instance, I have been told that in the context of Machine Learning, "noisy optimization" refers to optimizing a "noisy function" - that is, when you don't have the "exact deterministic form" of the function you want to optimize, but rather a series of measurements belonging to this function.

On principle, it is impossible in many practical settings to obtain the "exact deterministic form" of the function, and you only have discrete measurements belonging to this function - and these measurements can contain "noise". That means, if you were to record the same measurements again, the measurements may be different each time you record them.

**My Question:**  Have I correctly described what "Noisy Optimization" is? I am assuming that "Noisy Optimization Problems" was one of the reasons that "Evolutionary Algorithms" were first created, and that they continue to perform well on such problems (compared to Non-Evolutionary Problems)?

**References:**

- https://sigopt.com/blog/uncertainty-2-bayesian-optimization-with-uncertainty/

**Note:** I always wondered if theoretical convergence results could ever be established for optimization algorithms on "noisy functions" - but I am not sure if this is possible, seeing that this would largely depend on how "noisy" the function (i.e. quality of data) is.